# finite morphism and dimension of global sections of pullback

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $g:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of projective curves and $\mathcal{F}$ a
coherent sheaf on $Y$. is it true that $\dim H^0(X, g^*E) = deg(g) \dim H^0(Y, E)$?

Answer (score 8):

Far from it. When you come up with a conjecture it is worth looking at examples to test it.

The first example I thought of trying is the $2:1$ cover of $\mathbb P^1$ by itself. The pull-back of $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ is $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(2)$. The dimension of the space of global sections of the first is $2$, of the second is $3$. And then we're talking about the simplest possible non-trivial finite map between *smooth* projective curves and not allowing singularities or $\mathscr F$ being non-locally free. If you allow those conditions it just gets worse.

The statement is true if $\mathscr F$ is locally free and $g_*\mathscr O_X$ is a free $\mathscr O_Y$-module. In that case the proof goes like this:

$$
H^0(X, g^*\mathscr F) \simeq H^0(Y, g_*g^*\mathscr F) \simeq H^0(Y, \mathscr F\otimes g_*\mathscr O_X) \simeq H^0(Y, \mathscr F\otimes \mathscr O_Y^{\oplus r}) \simeq H^0(Y, \mathscr F)^{\oplus r}.
$$

Comment: Or just take $\mathcal F = \mathcal O_Y$.

Comment: I guess I didn't pick the simplest example. :)

Comment: The correct answer can be read from the last line of the Sandor's answer $H^0(X,g^*E) = H^0(Y,E\otimes g_*{\mathcal O}_Y)$. For example if $g:\PP^1 \to \PP^1$ is the 2-fold covering then $g_*{\mathcal O}_X = {\mathcal O}_Y \oplus {\mathcal O}_Y(-1)$, so $H^0(X,g^*E) = H^0(Y,E) \oplus H^0(Y,E(-1))$.